# Java: add JPanel class do a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to put a JPanel that I made in a specific class in the main JFrame of my aplication.

The jpanel class name is MainMenu and extends jpanel and has a norma constructor that initializates 2 buttons and a list

In the class that extends jframe i am trying:

```
    MainMenu MP = new MainMenu();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(MP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

also tryed something like this:

```
    getContentPane().add(MP);
```

the jframe is empty with no jpanel inside.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Call `pack` and `setVisible` AFTER adding the component not before.  Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: thank you
pack() solved the problem!!! Can you explain me what does it does? thank you again

Comment: `pack` causes a new layout pass to be executed - Swing layouts are lazy